# Problem regarding sql server to store hindi mangal devnagari font. Its showing square boxes when I try to insert the value

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, unicode

I am working with an module of NLP (Natural Language Processing). For that, I need to store hindi characters in to SQL Server 2005 table. For this, I am using c# as the frontend programming.

At first, I need to know whether the SQL Server stores the hindi characters in a table or not. So I am directly with out c# trying to store hindi characters into table using the Insert queries but its storing square boxes in the database.

I am using Mangal devnagri font for hindi fonts.

The datatype of the table columns is nvarchar(50). The collation is the default one i.e. 'SQL_Latin_General_....'. I have tried too much googling on this from many days but I am not able to find a satisfactory help.

Comment: The "font" should be irrelevant. A font relates to display/rendering, not storage. Where are you seeing the square boxes, exactly? I.e. If you are seeing this in the IDE (that night not be using your choice of font) it might make sense. I guess what I mean is: is the data stored intact?

Comment: I am trying to paste the hindi fonts from the character map application of windows to directly the Data View of the sql server table. But when I paste in sql server table, it shows the square boxes.

Comment: that isn't unexpected and doesn't mean anything

Comment: That's because only the Unicode characters, not the font used, is copied to the clipboard from the character map. The data view font cannot display those characters, so it displays placeholder boxes. You can change the font in the options, "Environment", "Fonts and Colors", then set the "Show settings for:" dropdown to "Data Viewer", and choose a font which includes those characters ("Arial Unicode MS" may be a good choice).

Comment: Thnx a lot guys.....Its working in sql servel but still c# show me "????"....

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you see the square boxes in SQL Server Management Studio. This is likely due to the wrong font being used for display there, and not necessarily a problem of the data being stored.

When you query the DB from your application and read the values, you should get the correct unicode representation back, so that no information is lost.

Make sure that you pass in data as `nvarchar` in parametrized queries (and if you pass literal strings, do prefix them with a "N", like so: `SET @s = N'My String'`).

Answer (score -1):

<s>You'll have to use another collation. Try a specific one meant for hindi characters. If you can't find any available, use a generic unicode/utf-8 one. I'm not using MSSQL, so you'll have to find the correct setting yourself (or wait for another reply). For mySQL I'd use the collation `utf8_general_ci`. Setting the collation to something "latin" essentially means it will be able to hold standard latin characters (e.g. A-Z) as well as some variants like ä, ó or û but it most likely won't be able to accept many non-latin characters.</s>

Try Lucero's approach above.

Comment: The collation has only effect regarding storage on non-unicode columns/data (of course it also controls case-sensitiveness and sort order for comparison, but that's not relevant for storage).

Comment: Okay, reread some release notes. So 'nvarchar' always represents a unicode string while 'varchar' is non-unicode? Learnt something new, although I don't understand their thoughts behind that naming convention.